# lombok 0.10.1. error in Eclipse 3.7

Tags: eclipse, lombok

when I try to use the `@Data` annotation with lombok `0.10.1`. in Eclipse: `3.7.0.v20110504-0800-7b7qFVpFEx2XnmYtj_9RfO7`

I got this error, can anyone advise?

```
Lombok annotation handler class lombok.eclipse.handlers.HandleData failed

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java/util/Arrays.copyOf([Ljava/lang/Object;I)[Ljava/lang/Object;
    at lombok.eclipse.handlers.EclipseHandlerUtil.createSuppressWarningsAll(EclipseHandlerUtil.java:514)
    at lombok.eclipse.handlers.EclipseHandlerUtil.injectMethod(EclipseHandlerUtil.java:451)
    at lombok.eclipse.handlers.HandleEqualsAndHashCode.generateMethods(HandleEqualsAndHashCode.java:227)
    at lombok.eclipse.handlers.HandleEqualsAndHashCode.generateEqualsAndHashCodeForType(HandleEqualsAndHashCode.java:116)
    at lombok.eclipse.handlers.HandleData.handle(HandleData.java:63)
    at lombok.eclipse.HandlerLibrary$AnnotationHandlerContainer.handle(HandlerLibrary.java:73)
    at lombok.eclipse.HandlerLibrary.handleAnnotation(HandlerLibrary.java:191)
    at lombok.eclipse.TransformEclipseAST$AnnotationVisitor.visitAnnotationOnType(TransformEclipseAST.java:204)
    at lombok.eclipse.EclipseNode.traverse(EclipseNode.java:96)
    at lombok.eclipse.EclipseAST.traverseChildren(EclipseAST.java:94)
    at lombok.eclipse.EclipseNode.traverse(EclipseNode.java:63)
    at lombok.eclipse.EclipseAST.traverseChildren(EclipseAST.java:94)
    at lombok.eclipse.EclipseNode.traverse(EclipseNode.java:58)
    at lombok.eclipse.EclipseAST.traverse(EclipseAST.java:89)
    at lombok.eclipse.TransformEclipseAST.go(TransformEclipseAST.java:166)
    at lombok.eclipse.TransformEclipseAST.transform(TransformEclipseAST.java:132)
    at lombok.eclipse.TransformEclipseAST.transform_swapped(TransformEclipseAST.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.endParse(Parser.java:8506)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.util.CommentRecorderParser.endParse(CommentRecorderParser.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.SourceElementParser.endParse(SourceElementParser.java:727)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:9515)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:9731)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:9688)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.SourceElementParser.parseCompilationUnit(SourceElementParser.java:921)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.indexing.SourceIndexer.indexDocument(SourceIndexer.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.JavaSearchParticipant.indexDocument(JavaSearchParticipant.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.indexing.IndexManager.indexDocument(IndexManager.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.indexing.IndexManager$1.execute(IndexManager.java:853)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.processing.JobManager.run(JobManager.java:405)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:799)
```

Comment: When and where do you get this error? In Eclipse’s error log, or in a pop-up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of this problem is that that version of lombok used java6 API, and I suppose you're using java5 to run eclipse. This has been fixed in the 0.10.4 release. The current version is 0.10.6.

Disclosure: I'm one of the core contributors.